# How can I choose node version for ng build command?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have two different version of node version installed - 11.6 and 13.6. 13.6v is set in path variable so that is default node. I have a project which needs to be built only using 11.6v. But my ng command is using node 13.6 by default (I checked this using ng --version). Is there anyway I can ask ng to use node from a specific folder where I have 11.6 installed instead of the default one.

Edit: This is on Jenkins VM, so I don't have much access to change things.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to work with different versions is using **nvm** tool.

See:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm